# problem with 2d array mallocation (segmentation fault)

Tags: c, memory-management

I tried to malloc a 2d array, but it gdb gives me Segmentation fault in line 8. It seems like something is wrong with if (A[i+x][j+y]!=A[i][j].

By the way: This program should print out the dimensions of the maximum square-sized sub-matrix of an input matrix, such that all its digits are equal matrix, such that all its digits are equal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int same_surrounding(int **A, int i, int j, int size){
  for (int x=0; x<size; x++){
    for (int y=0; y<size; y++){
      if (A[i+x][j+y]!=A[i][j])
        return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(){
  int n, i, j, sub, max_sub;
  int **A;

  scanf("%d", &n);
  A=malloc(sizeof*A*n);
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    A[i]=malloc(sizeof**A*n);
  }
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
      scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
      sub=1;
      while (sub<n&&same_surrounding(A, i, j, sub)){
        if (sub>max_sub)
          max_sub=sub;
        sub++;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%d", max_sub);  
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    free(A[i]);
  }
  free(A);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `same_surrounding` goes way outside the bounds of the array. Not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it, but it still gives me segmentation fault (core dumped). (see post-edit)

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 2 things wrong with this code:

1. Your program is checking for submatrices beyond the dimension of input matrix `n`. for example, if `n=5`,`i=3`,`j=0` and `sub=3` you can easily see that your code is checking for numbers in `A[i+x][j+y]` i.e. upto `A[5][2]` which is out of bound of `A`. You need to check this before sending it to `same_surrounding()`. For that all you need to do is slightlt change the `while` loop:

```
while (sub<=n && i+sub<n && j+sub<n && same_surrounding(A, i, j, sub)){...}
```

2. Always initialize your variables. Here you didn't initialize `max_sub` variable. When you don't initialize your variables, it contains random garbage value. For example if the garbage value is `478231` and you are looking for largest square matrix of 5x5 matrix, you'll never reach the condition `if (sub>max_sub)` and as a result `max_sub` will never update. That's why always initialize your variable with a safe value, for example, `max_sub=0`.

---

Also, as a warning, you should use `sizeof()` instead of explicitly writing the number of bytes necessary for memory allocation. Because they might change depending on computer architecture.

```
A=(int**) malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    A[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
}
```

---

[Here's the working version of your code.](https://onlinegdb.com/HklAdhJKB) All I did was some `{` `}` cleanup. If you have just one statement under `for`, `while`, `if` etc., you don't really need the braces.

Comment: be sure to mark the answer as solved. That would help me out! :)